# Application-defined or object-defined error with formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I get an "application-defined or object-defined error" with the last formula block in this code. The other two work fine, and the last formula, when inserted into a cell, works perfectly fine there, too.

Any ideas what throws the error?

```
Sub Wells_cartesian_to_spherical()
Range("M1").Value = "Boret lengde"
Range("NJ1").Value = "Asimuth"
Range("O1").Value = "Boret helning"

Dim RngX2 As Range
Set RngX2 = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 11)
RngX2.Formula = "=SQRT(((B2-I2)^2+(C2-J2)^2)+(D2-K2)^2)"
RngX2.Value = RngX2.Value

Dim RngY2 As Range
Set RngY2 = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 13)
RngY2.Formula = "=DEGREES(ASIN(SQRT((B2-I2)^2+(C2-J2)^2)/(SQRT(((B2-I2)^2+(C2-J2)^2)+(D2-K2)^2))))"
'RngY2.Value = RngY2.Value

Dim RngZ2 As Range
Set RngZ2 = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 12)
RngZ2.Formula = "=DEGREES(IF(I2-B2>0,(PI()/2)-((ATAN((J2-C2)/(I2-B2)))),IF(I2-B2<0,((3*PI())/2)-((ATAN((J2-C2)/(I2-B2)))),IF(J2-C2<0,PI(),0))))"
RngZ2.Value = RngZ2.Value
End Sub
```

The formula is used to calculate well depth, well orientation and well inclination for a drilled well given the x, y and z coordinates for the top and bottom of the well. Below is some comma separated sample data which should work with code:

```
Well no,X,Y,Z,Drilled length,Azimuth,Inclination,objtype,X bunn,Y bunn,Z bunn
28738,83124.42153,1233423.379,121,120,0,0,Energibrønn,83124.42153,1233423.379,1
29674,87717.14427,1237872.851,139.8000031,135,0,0,Energibrønn,87717.14427,1237872.851,4.800003052
29652,90488.64255,1242007.401,229.8000031,201,0,0,Energibrønn,90488.64255,1242007.401,28.80000305
28791,90899.79513,1243677.054,274.1000061,114,0,0,Energibrønn,90899.79513,1243677.054,160.1000061
29171,88224.0884,1233361.655,127.9000015,102,100,10,Energibrønn,88241.53142,1233358.579,27.44961072
30393,88204.31375,1233372.11,127.5999985,160,125,2,Energibrønn,88208.88783,1233368.907,-32.30253385
```

Just copy and paste to Excel. Please excuse any Norwegian characters/words ;)

Comment: I ran your code and didn't get any errors?

Comment: Hi, I just tried your code with your data and it works fine for me. Only thing is `Range("NJ1").Value = "Asimuth"` should probably be `N1` rather than `NJ1`. Even better: `Range("M1:O1").Value = Array("Bo..","As..","Bo..")` can replace all three of those lines.

Comment: How strange ... Then the error must lie somewhere else. I cannot see any reason why it should fail, so I'm stumped.

Comment: @CallumDA, I'm not sure what you mean. Where is the string you're referring to?

Comment: @CallumDA, Sorry, I saw it now

Comment: You can all make it work and I can't? What a bummer. I'll have to find another way to calculate it, then. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: Hi @LarsS, have you debugged your code at all? Try placing this line just before you set the last formula : `msgbox RngZ2.Address`. What does it return?

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the range is correct: $N$2:$N$7 for a list containing data in rows 2 to 7. The debug then highlights the formula as the problem.

Comment: What if you do `RngZ2.Formula = "=1"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140150/discussion-between-larss-and-callumda).

Comment: Works fine for me btw

Comment: I'm going to have to use native vba calculation instead of formulas as a workaround. If anyone has the time and inclination to help me paraphrase the formula into vba math expressions, I'd be a very happy man indeed.

Comment: Is this perhaps a Region/Locale issue? Commas instead of semi-colons etc.?

Comment: I suspect this might be so. I've transformed the code here into standard notation, but my formula works perfectly in local notation in an Excel cell. so do the other formulas in local notation. But I don't understand why tnat last bit does't work in vba when it works in Excel ...

Comment: Could you have an error value in any of the cells? I don't know if that would cause your problem. (Edit - guess on reflection it wouldn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to make a workaround using R1C1 notation. I just recorded a macro entering the formula and copied the resulting vba formula into the code. That worked. So the error must lie somewhere in the cell addressing. Thanks for all the input, guys.

```
Dim RngZ2 As Range
Set RngZ2 = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 12)
RngZ2.FormulaR1C1 = "=DEGREES(IF(RC[-5]-RC[-12]>0,(PI()/2)-((ATAN((RC[-4]-RC[-11])/(RC[-5]-RC[-12])))),IF(RC[-5]-RC[-12]<0,((3*PI())/2)-((ATAN((RC[-4]-RC[-11])/(RC[-5]-RC[-12])))),IF(RC[-4]-RC[-11]<0,PI(),0))))"
RngZ2.Value = RngZ2.Value
```